# How to add Array in a class to JLIST JAVA?

Tags: java, swing

I want to add the name of array in the class to jList as below.

How can it be?

this is the method in display class

```
    public void dataToLocal(List<XDataObject> data, XServiceType xst, XServiceOperation operation) {
            if(operation.getName().equals(SNOWTAMSubscriberServiceInterface.OP_PUBLISSNOWTAM)) {    
    SNOWTAMPublication snowtamPublication = 
    (SNOWTAMPublication)data.get(0).getValue(); //This read an array with 5 values.

        SNOWTAM snowtam = snowtamPublication.getSNOWTAM()[0]; //This read read the array and its contents.

        jList1.add((Component) Arrays.asList((snowtamPublication.getSNOWTAM()[0]).toString())); //Here I want to add the name of Array to be as below
    }
}
```

This is SNOWTAMPublication which is only get and set methods for array.

```
protected SNOWTAM[] snowtam;

public SNOWTAM[] getSNOWTAM() {
    if(snowtam == null)
    {
        snowtam = new SNOWTAM[0];
    }
    return snowtam;
}

public void setSNOWTAM(SNOWTAM[] _value) {
    this.snowtam = _value;
}
```

The picture

[image]

Comment: You should do this on list model: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: I tried to add more details to be clear @GhostCat

Comment: @Antoniossss List model does not help

Comment: Thing is: **clarify** what you want to achieve. It is *not* clear what exactly you want to show up in that list. Arrays dont have "names"; they have *content*. Plus: "list model does not help" doesn't help either. Why does it not help you? That link explains to you **how** you properly manage the information that a list will display. How can that *not* be helpful?

Comment: @GhostCat I think I wrote in the beginning add the name of array in the class to jList

Comment: Which part of "arrays do not have names" do you not understand?

Comment: @GhostCat I wrote the name of Array. It means SNOWTAM for example in this case.

Comment: Sigh. You are using the term SNOWTAM, and snowtam ... but your code doesn't make it clear at all what this is about. In other words: you use the same word (just different CASE) as class name, as field name and what not. Maybe it is just "wording"; and you edit the question to use a "meaningful" word?!

Comment: @GhostCat. Oh, the code will write only (snowtam). I wrote as a text to make it clear only. What you see is a part of 6 packages and many classes

Comment: @GhostCat I change the output to be clear. The same code input will be an output

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

```
<instance>.getClass().getSimpleName()
```